# How do I detect when the flash for the AVCaptureDevice has finished and still image capture has begun?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I am making a pretty simple/standard camera app that uses a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. When the user presses a button, I call captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection on the AVCaptureStillImageOutput to capture an image. At the time that I capture the image, I animate a simple white UIView over the preview layer as an indication to the user that a photo is being captured, and hide it again after the image capture is complete.

My problem is that when the camera flash is on, I don't want to display the white view immediately because the photo capture doesn't actually happen until after the flash has gone off. Is there a way to determine that the flash has finished or that the image capture has actually begun? Perhaps via KVO, NSNotificationCenter, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using KVO on the `capturingStillImage` property of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`.

The documentation reads like that may be what you need.